# Some files have been deleted when conflicts occurs after merging in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, git-merge

I'm using git for Visual Studio. I merged two branches and some conflicts occurred. Visual studio automatically deleted two files without any confirmation. How can I prevent VS to delete files while it try to resolves conflicts automatically.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio didn't delete those files; they were already deleted.  You picked out two files with their status of "deleted by us".  This means that in your HEAD branch, the file has been deleted and it has not been modified in the branch that you're merging in.  This is not a conflict (but Visual Studio is showing you a report of what is going on in the merge).

If there had been a change to that file that you're merging in, *that* would be a conflict, and you would be prompted to either restore the file (with the changes from the remote branch) or keep the deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Before commit the merge, use `git diff --name-status HEAD` to find if some files have been deleted. And if you want to keep the files just use `git reset HEAD <file>` to unstage the deleted files.

And if the merge have been finished by automatically, use `git diff --name-status HEAD HEAD~1` to find the deleted files. And if you want to keep the files, `git reset HEAD~1` to reset the merge commit. And then just commit the modification you want to commit and reset what you want to keep.

And to get rid of auto-commit, just use `git merge --no-commit <branch>`, And then the first solution can be OK.